# /dev/kvm not found on mac

Tags: macos, android-studio, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device

So I've been working with android studio 2.0 beta on my Mac and AVD was working fine.

But then I notice that android studio can't launch AVD now. It says **/dev/kvm not found.  enable VT-x in your bios security settings, ensure that your linux distro has working kvm module**.

[image]

The thing is: I didn't touch bios settings at all. Possible causes :

- VMWare - I was playing with virtual machines and configuring new networks for vm's just before I noticed the error.
- CleanMyMac - I also used this app to clean the system
- other causes are possible, but I never entered BIOS or touched system settings

The solutions on resolving this issue I found all refer to Linux, rather than Mac. How would I fix this?

EDIT:

I reinstalled OS X (without formatting hard drive). That didn't work.

Comment: my mac doesn't even have a /dev/kvm. have you considered reinstalling AS and AVD? A.S 2.0 is out of beta now, might be more stable.

Comment: Did you update your android studio/avd or intel haxm?

Comment: I tried reinstalling android studio 2.0 but no luck.

Comment: This is the corrrect and easy way https://stackoverflow.com/a/46733691/1928414

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove the previous HAXM and install IntelHAXM_6.0.3.dmg in haxm-macosx_v6_0_3.zip

here is download link [haxm-macosx_v6_0_3.zip](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement-macosx)

its work for me!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. It works for me too on mac os.

Comment: @Md.Tahmid Bin Rashid- I have downloaded HAXM and installed successfully but I am still getting the same error /dev/kvm not found. What to do now?

Comment: @SurabhiPandey Did you uninstall your previously install HAXM and after that install HAXM here https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases and restart your pc. if latest version HAXM can not solve your issue try to use some older one. i have same problem 4 years ago and i'm try this to solve my problem.

Answer (score 16):

Here is the solution that worked me.

Well, Android Studio need HAXM to run emulator.

The issue is that the HAXM drivers doesn’t support the beta version of Mac Os High Serria yet.

The driver works but with a little bit of additional command.

First, you will need to disable the Security Protection on kext. The drivers is not sign for this version.

From [https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/269777](https://sck.pm/mIj):

1. Get into Recovery Mode by restarting and holding down ⌘+R until Apple logo appears.
2. In the top menu click Utilities > Terminal.
3. In the Terminal window type and press Enter:

   csrutil enable --without kext
4. Then restart the Mac.

Then you can install HAXM from:

Download the driver from here [https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/](https://sck.pm/ttc) and unzip it.

Open a terminal and go to the directory of the driver :

```
cd Downloads/haxm-macosx_v6_2_0
# edit the file and look for 10.12
nano silent_install.sh
CTRL + W
10.12
```

Add 10.13 after 10.12, and save the file ( CTRL+X, Y, ENTER)

Run it:

```
./silent_install.sh
```

To be sure it works:

```
sudo kextload -bundle-id com.intel.kext.intelhaxm
```

Now your emulator should work !

Comment: This allows intel emulators to run, but /dev/kvm still doesn't show up using ls /dev/kvm

Comment: Thanks ! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Looks like it's not related to Beta version, I still have to do these steps on production version

Answer (score 4):

**/dev/kvm** not found on mac.

Follow the steps. You can solve your problem.

**Step1:** Download Intel HAXM from [software.intel.com](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement-macosx).

**Step2:** Extract and Open the file name like “IntelHAXM_6.2.1.dmg”.

**Step3:** Double click on “IntelHAXM_6.2.1.mpkg” to Install manually.

**Step4:** Read and Install carefully.

**Step5:** When you receive Security warning for new extension goto system preferences and Click “Allow” button.

**Step6:** That’s it. Now you can run the emulator.

> (Note : Incase you get same error again. Please Re-Install the
>   “IntelHAXM_6.2.1.mpkg” Once again. That’s really fix your problem.)

Happy coding... :-)

Comment: In my case, need to go to System Preference > Security&Privacy > General >  Allow Intel Corp Apps, then reinstall again finally fix it.

Comment: Yeah. step 5 says same. Thanks for exact procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Enter your VM settings and then search for virtualization engine : 
Check the virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-RVI option.
This should resolve the problem.

Comment: I removed all of the virtual machines after the incident. that didn't seem to help

Answer (score 0):

Your MacOS need to enable Intel VT-x
[image]

Reference:
[enable Intel VT-x](https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-macOS#System_Requirements)