# Android Studio Emulator "/dev/kvm is not found"

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator

Couldn't use x86 emulators, AVD manager shows warning "/dev/kvm is not found" and telling me to edit BIOS security setting to enable VT-x.[image]

Comment: I got the same error in Ubuntu. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I had the same problem: couldn't run AVD (image Nougat x86_64).
As [makthrow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40431889/6485987), how I solved: just enabled *Intel Virtualization Technology* in BIOS (*BIOS Features* section for my Gigabyte motherboard). Note: SDK Manager show for *Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)*: "Not compatible with Linux" and it is not possible to install.

Comment: This Helped me, on macOS High Sierra: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44942860/502404

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Re-installing HAXM resolved my problem
Steps:

1. Make sure `SDK Manager -> Extras -> Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` is installed
2. Navigate to `<sdk>/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/`
3. Run `./HAXM\ installation -u`
4. Run `./HAXM\ installation`

Comment: Under MacOS X I have to allow also the installation under "Security & Privacy"

Comment: It gives me "Permission Denied" I also tried to execute it after "sudo su" and using my admin password.

Comment: `./HAXM\ installation` gives installation failed

Comment: On ubuntu I don't see the 'extras'

Answer (score 45):

For MacOS users running Android Studio, when you get this error then try these steps to open up your privacy settings.

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can also follow the answer from Divakar on this post here - [/dev/kvm not found on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325612/dev-kvm-not-found-on-mac)

Thank you Apple for pushing me with your dumb*** app review rules from iOS to android development

Comment: I needed to both reinstall and give permissions

Answer (score 2):

You just need to "start" the HAXM. You can do this following this steps:

1. Open the cmd.
2. Type `sc query intelhaxm`, click enter and check the STATE.
3. If state is **1 STOPED**, type `sc start intelhaxm` and click enter to start the HAXM.
4. Check the STATE again and it should be **4 RUNNING** now.
5. Finally, you are now able to create and use your AVD using a x86 emulator.

Alternatively, when you want to stop the HAXM you should type `sc stop intelhaxm`.

Hope this helps y'all.

Comment: [SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus: Open Service FAILED 1060

Specified service does not exist as an installed service.

Comment: in my case when i started to start the intelhaxm it gave message "windows can not verity the digital signature for this file. a recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged"

Comment: Hi Abdul Wahid, I am also getting the same error message after running "sc start intelhaxm". May I know what is the Issue and what is the solution for this ?Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar message in the emulators area in Android Studio 2.1.

My emulator for a certain API (think 21) worked initially fine and was fully accelerated, then installed a couple of other images (Nougat x86/64 etc) and suddenly started seeing /dev/kvm not found and NO emulator would boot up.

- In My Case, re-installing HAXM sadly did not help, but rebooting my MAC did (go figure).
- But, I also noted that if you have installed an emulator image but not the related SDK for the API (which makes sense), then you get a similar pop-up when starting the emulator, which makes you think it may be a HAXM / KVM issue, which its not.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Update Bios Setting

1. Power on the system and press[delete] key to enter BIOS [EZ Mode]
2. Press [F7] key to enter BIOS [Advance Mode] as below picture：
   (If press [delete] key to enter [Advanced Mode] directly and then no need to press [F7] key any more)
3. Select  [Advanced] page and click [CPU Configuration] item
4. Select [Intel(VMX) Virtualization Technology] item and set to [Enabled]
5. Press [F10] key and click [OK] ,the system will auto reboot

   [image: enter code here]

Comment: Thank you @Falansh Siddh Its work perfect at my side

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS, After installing make sure to allow Intel HAXM under "Security & Privacy".

This was the only way I was able to run the Android Emulator :)

Comment: I'm trying to allow but it doesn't anything [like this screencast](https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/2x3z0p1U3r2o390x0d1t/Screen%20Recording%202017-11-25%20at%2008.22%20PM.gif?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=1399595&v=e4263c32). What should I do?

Comment: Maybe try to restart your mac? That button should work :o

Comment: I found a solution from [here](https://blog.celogeek.com/201708/672/android-studio-emulator-haxm-on-mac-os-high-serria-10-13/) which recommends disable MacOS system protection (only for Kernel Extensions) and its worked. But I'm worried about this way for decreasing for my security. :( I hope I can find a safer way in future.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling and restarting did not work for me. Instead, I had to start my Mac in Recovery Mode (restart & press ⌘+R until Apple logo appears). Then open terminal from Utilities drop down menu. Type and run:

```
csrutil enable --without kext
```

You will get some warnings and instruction to restart for the changes to take effect. Restart and the emulator will run this time.

Reference:
https://blog.celogeek.com/201708/672/android-studio-emulator-haxm-on-mac-os-high-serria-10-13/

Answer (score 0):

Just go to terminal and type

```
sudo chown 777 -R /dev/kvm,
```

then type

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/kvm.
```

And restart android studio

And that's it..

In some case it may happened that for every start of android studio you need to type this commands First and then start android studio.

Comment: chown: -R: No such file or directory
chown: /dev/kvm,: No such file or directory

Comment: This only works if /dev/kvm exists, which in quite some cases it doesnt.

Comment: My KVM doesnt exist on Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't install mine because I had HyperV enabled on my machine. Removed it and I was able to install the HAXM from the following link:

https://github.com/intel/haxm

Answer (score 0):

Either your CPU does not support virtualization, or it is disabled in the bios. Go into your bios and see if you can find a setting to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution that worked for me was to go to my PC BIOS which i'm running an Ubuntu OS on and shutting it down and turning it on pressing the F10 key which boots it up to the BIOS and navigate to **Advance Option** > **System Options** and **enabling both Vitualization Technology(VTX)** and **Vitualization Technology for Directed I/O(VTd)** then save and exit and this should restart your PC and now try running the emulator.

Answer (score -2):

I tried reinstalling HAXM a few times but kept getting the errors.

In my case I actually had to go into Bios Settings and enable Virtualization.

It worked for me. Just in case this helps anyone.

Comment: This is for OSX and your solution is a windows solution