# Android Studio shows that Intel Haxm is not installed, but it is installed

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I have Intel Haxm installed on my system according to the "Programs and Features" option in Control Panel. But in my SDK manager, under Intel Haxm it says that Haxm installer is not compatible with Windows.

When I run an app from a virtual device it gives the following error:

[image]

[image]

I tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812624/android-studio-emulator-dev-kvm-is-not-found) but was unable to locate the SDK folder.
It was not there in the "Android" folder. Only "Android Studio" folder is present there.

When I run the Intel haxm-android.exe again it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwgaO.jpg). If I run silent-install.bat it gives the error that the system does not have the path specified.

UPDATE: I was able to find the sdk folder. I went to:

```
<sdk>/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/
```

When I intelhaxm-android.exe, it shows here that the Haxm is already installed.

Comment: If all else fails, Genymotion runs great and smooth.