# Can't launch AVD on macOS 10.13

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-studio-3.0, macos-high-sierra

I created some AVDs in Android studio 3.0, but I can't launch them. I used the following command to launch them:

```
./emulator @Nexus_5X_API_17
```

logs:

```
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
Failed to open vm 3
Failed to create HAX VM
No accelerator found.
failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument
```

And when I reinstalled "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer)", the logs:

```
HAXM silent installation only supports macOS from 10.8 to 10.12 !
```

I don't know if it is related with this.

After that, I tried to install virtualBox to install genymotion, but I found when I clicks the virturalBox.dmg, the installer crashed.

Could you help me? thanks.

Comment: this worked for me 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67288845/8899344

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use the new Hypervisor.Framework support instead of HAXM on macOS, as described in the comments of the [issue filed for this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62395878):

> Try running the emulator on Canary channel 26.1.x (API 25/26
>   recommended) with Hypervisor.Framework; put the text "HVF = on" in
>   ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini (create this file if it doesn't exist
>   already).

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help me

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, there is now an easier solution, which is to just install HAXM version 6.2.1 (see the answer by @freeman-wang).

Comment: Worked for me but I had to restart my mac after this settings.

Comment: WHat is a hypervisor.framework? does anyone have any better instructions then the above. I'm not really understanding the solution.

Comment: There are 20 links on that google site. You should copy the relevant link here to make your answer worthwhile.

Comment: This worked for me, I only had to restart Android Studio after updating the ini file.

Comment: This worked for me too, just need to restart macOS after this

Answer (score 35):

You can download and install the latest version haxm
https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/latest

Comment: Worked for me, though I needed a restart afterwards.

Comment: I followed the instructions on your link to install HAXM version 6.2.1 and this  fixed the issue for me (but like @JohnShammas, I also had to restart my computer after the installation).

Comment: HAXM will not install for MacOS 10.13

Comment: I have this issue in High Sierra but it is fixed in the latest version, currently 6.2.1 solved the issue to me. 
Make sure you got the right version running: kextstat | grep intel
In my case it was fixed after the reboot.Good luck!

Comment: On macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 and  Android Studio 3.0.1 - updating to HAXM 6.2.1 then a system restart fixed it for me.

Answer (score 22):

### Following steps worked for me:

1. Uninstall HAXM from android studio SDK manager (Tools->Android->SDK Manager->SDK Tools then uninstall 'Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM)' by unchecking it.
2. Download the HAXM version 6.2.1 zip file from Intel site https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement-macosx
3. Install the .dmg file
4. Restart your computer
5. Open your AVD having x86_64 image and it should work.

Comment: HAXM silent installation only supports macOS from 10.8 to 10.12 !

Comment: Macbook restart was required for me.

Comment: @gderaco Run the dmg install, not the silent install. Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Go to your SDK installation directory, and manually run the HAXM installer. See step 4 on the page: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#vm-mac

Technically HAXM is only officially supported up until [MacOS 10.12 (Sierra)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x) . Since MacOS 10.13 is still in beta, there may be a bug or incompatible API.  If the wizard does no work, please file a bug here for the Android Emulator dev team to investigate further: https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs

Comment: this actually helped... it was installed but for some reason not started so emulator was auto closed just after start without any further info

Answer (score 4):

Go to Tools->Android->SDK Manager, then in the SDK tools search for Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) and update to the latest version, restart and thats all!

Comment: This works. Simplest. Restart mac, not just android studio.

Comment: @JiteshW
Restart mac, not just android studio!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On install/reinstall of HAXM you get:

> HAXM silent installation only supports macOS from 10.8 to 10.12 !

From https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62395878#comment44

> in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General, there was a message “System software from developer xxx was blocked from loading.” with an Allow button. Clicking the allow button enabled HAXM again

Comment: Also described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2459/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017658-CH1-TNTAG3

Answer (score 0):

I just redownloaded the simulator and it worked.