# Android Device Manager fails to launch after updating to MacOS Big Sur 11.3

Tags: android, macos, emulation

So my Mac just forced updated to Big Sur 11.3. I've been trying to access the Android Device Manager to run an emulated device and it has been silently failing each time. When I tried to run it from the command line, I get this error message:

```
emulator @Pixel_3a_API_30
emulator: Android emulator version 30.5.5.0 (build_id 7285888) (CL:N/A)
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
cannot add library /Users/centuryfall/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
added library /Users/centuryfall/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib
cannot add library /Users/centuryfall/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib: failed
HVF error: HV_ERROR
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize HVF: Invalid argument
Failed to open the hax module
No accelerator found.
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize HAX: Operation not supported by device
added library /Users/centuryfall/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib
```

(Replaced actual username with "centuryfall").

I've looked at some other questions that say that the AVD needs to be version 30. I have AVD v30.5.5.0 Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: I wonder if you need to reinstall HAXM in the Android Studio settings

Comment: Ho Yes.... same issue here..

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Update 2021-04-29: Emulator version 30.5.6 now in stable channel and it fixes this issue. Old answer preserved below.

---

Apple has changed hypervisor entitlements (permissions), deprecating `com.apple.vm.hypervisor` with `com.apple.security.hypervisor`. Before Google fixes emulator code signing with the new entitlements you can work around the issue by granting the entitlement yourself.

Create a file `entitlements.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.hypervisor</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and run

```
codesign -s - --entitlements entitlements.xml --force /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
```

Replace qemu path as necessary where your SDK is located. Could be e.g. `~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64` on some SDK installations.

Answer based on https://www.arthurkoziel.com/qemu-on-macos-big-sur/

Related issues:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181142249
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186436367

Comment: Lost only one day trying to get it to work, could be worse lol. Thanks !

Comment: If the above doesn't work, check if you are using the 32bit version of Qemu, then qemu-system-x86_64 should be replaced with qemu-system-i386. Likewise for other architectures.

Comment: Hi all, I can also not start the emulator. But my error message is different. Can you take a look for me, if they are the same problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67307381/android-emulator-can-not-start-after-update-to-ios-big-sur-11-3-today

Comment: Awesome solution fixed for me. Also a new version of Android Emulator 3.5.6 got release yesterday [28/4], does minor update fix the issue? Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Emulator 30.5.6 didn't fix it for me. Going to try this workaround

Comment: I am tried above but getting below error:
qemu-system-x86_64: replacing existing signature
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
qemu-system-x86_64: the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used

Answer (score 6):

Update your emulator to get rid of this issue.

Follow the steps below:

In your android studio go to SDK Manager -> SDK Tools Tab

1. Select Android Emulator and update it

OR

1. Uncheck Android Emulator and apply
2. Check Android Emulator and apply

If you want to stay with the Android Emulator version below 30.5.6
you can follow the steps mentioned in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67288329/android-device-manager-fails-to-launch-after-updating-to-macos-big-sur-11-3/67288845#67288845)

Comment: Yes, I've seen the patch and have already updated my emulator. I had asked the question prior to that release being pushed, and I've already accepted the earlier answer above as the solution that I've needed.

Comment: Yeah, but many guys are not aware of this patch. So this answer will help them so upvote will help others in terms of visibility & fixing it when they will run in to this situation.

Comment: Confirmed this worked for me. I installed Android studio today and I had to use Tools->SDK Manager->SDK Tools

Comment: This is what did it for me. I already had the latest version of the Android Emulator installed, but removing and re-adding it with these steps resolved the issue

Answer (score 2):

If you get `entitlements.xml: cannot read entitlement data` error you should start  the terminal at folder which include qemu-system-x86_64 file.

For example my `qemu-system-x86_64` file is in this location : `/Users/yourusername/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64`

Now right click on `darwin-x86_64` folder and click `New terminal Tab at Folder`. Don't forget the copy your `entitlements.xml` file into the `darwin-x86_64` folder. Now in this terminal run the command which @laalto said. If you have any question, i'll gladly answer.

Comment: Thank you. Putting together your instructions and @laalto's command made it work for me. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

For those who using Xamarin:

**Visual Studio Mac** Go to Preference. Click on Android, it will prompt you for SDK repair. Click on it and it should fix it.

[image]

If you are using **Rider**, go Preference, Android and update the Emulator SDK:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I installed Android studio today and confirmed that updating is still needed.

Use Tools->SDK Manager->SDK Tools to update the two packages. Then make a new emulator.

Now `emulator --version` shows 30.6.5.0 and the command `emulator -avd tak -gpu host` launches the hardware accelerated emulator without an issue.

Side note: The emulator output still throws two "cannot add library" lines that are followed by "added library" though it seems to launch just fine.

P.s. Don't forget to set your environment variables in your .bashrc or .zshrc

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/dan/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/dan/Library/Android/sdk/emulator"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/dan/Library/Android/sdk/tools"
```