# Android Emulator Issue with Arctic Fox on Big Sur

Tags: android-emulator, macos-big-sur, android-studio-arctic-fox

I am using **Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 on Mac Big Sur** once after creating AVD with:
Below Spec:
[image]

When I run the AVD new emulator-5554 getting created, and also after some time getting a message like AVD timeout300 seconds...

And even not able to debug

Comment: trying this solution :https://stackoverflow.com/a/67288845/1089841
but getting qemu-system-x86_64: replacing existing signature xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun qemu-system-x86_64: the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used