# Android Emulator Freeze in Big Sur

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, macos-big-sur

Hey I update my Big Sur 11.6.2 and my Android Studio is

[image]

I am trying to run emulator and it open correctly. After opening emulator is automatically freeze and after that not working. Sometime it working very slowly. Even I am getting **System UI isn't responding message** or sometimes it reboot automatically. I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67288845/11560810) as well, but it won't work.

[image]

Comment: have you tried increase ram space of your emulator

Comment: Yes I tried that

Comment: maybe you can reinstall android studio again it may help have you tried your app to run in real device

Comment: Ok I'll try to reinstall again android studio and I tried my application in real device is working fine

Comment: @sashabeliy nothing works. It's freeze the emulator :(