# How to enable vtx and kvm module on windows

Tags: android

I'm using Dell inspiron laptop with i3 processor and using windows 7 OS.While using Android Studio I'm encountering a problem with AVD. When I try to run it, it shows error:

> Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. /dev/kvm is not found. Enable
>   VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has
>   working KVM module.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812624/android-studio-emulator-dev-kvm-is-not-found) for a thread on '/dev/kvm is not found'

Follow this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOfN8byV9uo) for Youtube video on how to enable intel VT-x in windows 10. There should be slight differences on how the interface looks in win 7.

And after following all this and you still cannot run your AVD with HAXM, like I encountered, just reboot. After this, everything worked well for me.