# Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD, /dev/kvm is not found

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, haxm

AVD doesn't work on macos 10.13, I tried several solution, it didn't work either.

I did install 'Intel X86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer)'. and tried downloaded and installed it from intel official website manually. it still get failed

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm
[image]
[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks,

Comment: have you already try the steps mentioned here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36812625/1008011

Comment: Yes, I did. but my os doesn't support ./HAXM\ installation -u, it said your os doesn't support silent install.