# Android Studio emulator on Mac not working

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a MacBook Air and I am trying to make a virtual emulator.
every time I try to run it, it says "

Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. /dev/kvm is not found.

Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your linux bistro has working KVM module 
"

please help

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812624/android-studio-emulator-dev-kvm-is-not-found ?

Comment: Click Command + Space and search for 'Security & Privacy' and then you should find System software from developer "Intel Corporation Apps" was blocked from loading. Click 'allow'

Comment: OMG THANKS i letterally called google apple and was just on the phone with intel

Comment: mmmmm.... Linux Bistro

Comment: @AbdulRahmanASamad Please make that an answer so that other people can find this.

Comment: @JimGarrison somehow I can't add as an answer because the question have been marked as duplicate.

Comment: It's OK, the duplicate is the same answer.