# Hardware acceleration is installed but Visual Studio for Mac can't find it. How do I proceed?

Tags: android, visual-studio-mac, haxm

I installed Visual Studio last year and have been using it for .Net development. Everything has been working fine so far. I use XCode for IOS development. I want to start doing Android development. When I try to use the emulator I get the following message:

> emulator: WARNING: encryption is off emulator: ERROR: x86_64 emulation
>   currently requires hardware acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is
>   properly installed and usable. CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not
>   installed on this machine (/dev/HAX is missing).

I took its word for it and installed Intel HAXM. While installing, HAXM said it was already installed and asked if I really wanted to continue. I assumed that the previous installation had issues and told it to continue. When the dust settled I was back to where I started. Visual Studio for Mac still claims that HAXM is not installed.

What do I do now?

Android apps do run on a connected device (i.e. the problem is limited to running on emulation devices).

**System Configuration**: 
MacOS High Sierra - 
Mac Mini (Mid 2010), 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 
16 GB 1067 MHz DDR3, 
NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB

Comment: Is there a reason you want to develop in Xamarin and not Java or Kotlin?

Comment: Lazy, just trying the "easy" one first (I already have the tools installed and know the libraries). The intent is to try out all the alternatives before settling on something. If this works well I could share code across Android, IOS and the web. If things continue the way they are going I will end up with three different tool and ecosystems (which is not the worst thing that could happen). Do you think it is not worth the effort?

Comment: If you want to get familiar with the Android system, Kotlin might be a better language. From what I know of Swift, the syntax is very similar.

Comment: Well, @TheWanderer seems like there is a bigger problem. I tried to install Android Studio and it also claims that it is "Unable to install Intel HAXM". Seems like HAXM doesn't work with Core 2 Duos running OSX.

Comment: Which Core 2 Duo exactly?

Comment: System Configuration: MacOS High Sierra - Mac Mini (Mid 2010), 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 16 GB 1067 MHz DDR3, NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB

Comment: Well that CPU does support VT-x, so HAXM should work. Have you tried rebooting or installing it through the Android SDK Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is similar to [/dev/kvm is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812624/android-studio-emulator-dev-kvm-is-not-found). Intel HAXM is not being installed properly because it is being blocked by "Security & Privacy". OSX has a wonderful security design. If it blocks something it does not tell you. If you do something else before checking you will never know what happened because it hides the message stating what was blocked.

To address this problem re-install [Intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement-macosx). Open [image] select [image] allow Intel HAXM

[image]

In my case, I had done other things after installing Intel HAXM so I did not have the option to "Allow" it. I had to go through the complete install process again before the option appeared. In addition, I found a long list of other things that had been blocked.