# How to enable VT-x in BIOS and KVM modules on Linux?

Tags: android, linux, virtual-machine, kvm

I have Dell Inspiron 15 5000 Series laptop containing intel core i5 6200U processor. I am using Windows 10 Home edition. It has the virtualization device and I already checked in BIOS for the virtualization, which is enabled.
But in android studio I am getting this error when I run AVD manager.

> Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that you Linux
>   distro has working KVM modules.

Answer (score 53):

As I understand, you've already enabled the VT-x option in BIOS. That's good. Because you have Linux as your operating system, now you need to install and configure KVM.

Instructions: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator

> **KVM Installation**
>
> I referred the instructions from Ubuntu community documentation page.
>   to get KVM installed.To see if your processor supports hardware
>   virtualization, you can review the output from this command:
>
> `$ egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo`
>
> If the output is 0 it means that your CPU doesn't support hardware
>   virtualization.
>
> Next is to install CPU checker:
>
> `$ sudo apt-get install cpu-checker`
>
> Now you can check if your cpu supports kvm:
>
> `$ sudo kvm-ok`
>
> and insert root password
>
> If you see:
>
> > "INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions KVM acceleration can be used"
>
> It means you can  run your virtual machine faster with the KVM
>   extensions.
>
> If you see:
>
> > "INFO: KVM is disabled by your BIOS HINT: Enter your BIOS
> >      setup and enable Virtualization Technology (VT), and then hard
> >      poweroff/poweron your system KVM acceleration can NOT be used"
>
> You need to go to BIOS setup and enable the VT.
>
> **Use a 64 bit kernel**
>
> Running a 64bit kernel on the host operating system is recommended
>   since Google no longer offers support for 32bit kernel.. This allows
>   the serving of more than 2GB of RAM for your VMs. Also, a 64-bit
>   system can host both 32-bit and 64-bit guests. A 32-bit system can
>   only host 32-bit guests. To see if your processor is 64-bit, you can
>   run this command:
>
> `$ egrep -c ' lm ' /proc/cpuinfo`
>
> If 0 is printed, it means that your CPU is not 64-bit. If 1 or higher,
>   it is. Note: lm stands for Long Mode which equates to a 64-bit CPU.
>   Now see if your running kernel is 64-bit, just issue the following
>   command:
>
> $ `uname -m`
>
> x86_64 indicates a running 64-bit kernel. If you see i386, i486, i586
>   or i686, you're running a 32-bit kernel.
>
> **Install KVM**
>
> For Ubuntu Lucid (12.04 LTS Precise) or later:
>
> `$ sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils`
>
> If it is displayed, you may ignore the Postfix Configuration below by
>   selecting "No Configuration"
>
> Next is to add your  account to the group kvm and libvirtd
>
> `$ sudo adduser your_user_name kvm`
>
> `$ sudo adduser your_user_name libvirtd`
>
> After the installation, you need to relogin so that your user account
>   becomes an effective member of kvm and libvirtd user groups. The
>   members of this group can run virtual machines.
>
> Verify Installation You can test if your install has been successful
>   with the following command:
>
> `$ sudo virsh -c qemu:///system list`

Hope that helps.

EDIT: As you may be running Windows instead of Linux, please follow the instructions in this post instead: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Comment: Sorry I did not mention above... I have Windows 10 Home Edition OS installed.

Comment: I added a link to solution for Windows. You may also try Genymotion emulator which is based on VirtualBox, so you don't need HAXM/KVM virtual machine

Comment: I am getting error in HAXM installation. "Failed to configure driver: unknown error. Failed to open driver."

Comment: Check this link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/04/25/workaround-patch-for-haxm-installation-error-failed-to-configure-driver-unknown

Comment: works like a charm.  Ubuntu 15.  UPVOTED :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue on mac os x, then follow below solution

Just remove the previous HAXM and install IntelHAXM_6.0.3.dmg in haxm-macosx_v6_0_3.zip

here is download link haxm-macosx_v6_0_3.zip

its work for me!
Ref: 
[/dev/kvm not found on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325612/dev-kvm-not-found-on-mac)