# Issue In Creating Emulator in Android Studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-2.3

We are trying to create an emulator but while creating emulator it is showing `dev/kvm not found` message. When we tried to resolve this issue by re-installing HAXM, every time we are getting the following message:

> Enable VT-x in your BIOS security, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM

We also checked the BIOS setting, the virtualization is enabled in system BIOS.

Request you to please provide your input for the same.

Please find the required details below:

Android Studio: `v2.2.3`
OS: Windows `7 64 bit`

Comment: maybe try http://stackoverflow.com/a/37087409/6085135

Comment: Try removing Intel HAXM from control panel and installing it manually ..