# Android Studio Emulator Error In Linux

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

SHOWS ERROR LIKE

```
> Emulator: warning: host doesn't support requested feature:
  CPUID.80000001H:ECX.abm [bit 5]
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Have you enabled the VT-x option in BIOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same message, but I do not think it has something to do with installing virtualbox but with the cpu, the emulator and the emulated system image (Android P). In my environments (linux, ubuntu 18.04 or debian 9) the message appears on my old sandybridge laptops but is not present on more modern skylake and kaby lake cpus and on all environments virtualbox is installed. However, **the emulator seems to work fair enough** on the sandy bridge machines with the warning. Let us hope that the old cpus continue to run the emulator for some time despite the warning and are not excluded by the emulator team @google in the near future.

Comment: i don't say that virtualbox is correct answer but at a time after virtual box installation according to suggation is solve my problem

Comment: I confirm that this `warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.abm` shows up on my Dell Inspiron 7720 laptop with Intel i7-3610QM CPU when running AVD on Ubuntu Budgie 18.04. But emulator works flawlessly

Comment: The emulator is not usable in my computer (i7-3632QM, Ivi Bridge). When I launch the emulator, after just a few seconds the processor reaches temperatures above 100 ºC. I almost killed my netbook with Android Studio 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Enable the VT-x option in BIOS and check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087365/how-to-enable-vt-x-in-bios-and-kvm-modules-on-linux) to enable KVM to run emulator.

Comment: vtx was enabled in bios