# /dev/kvm is not found on Mac OS

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

I recently updated my Macbook pro to Mac OS High Sierra. Now I'm running into an issue where I can no longer start the emulator in Android Studio.

The warning `/dev/kvm is not found.` is shown. When I tried to start the emulator I get the following error:

[image]

I tried different versions of Intel HAXM from the SDK manager and standalone, reinstalling Android Studio and completely removing all configurations, still the same issue..

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. Go to: 
   System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General

There should be a message like “System software from developer xxx was blocked from loading.”

2. Click Allow

Comment: Wow, I have tried so many things from installing the HAXM and even doing some weird thing in recovery mode and this is all i needed. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing, you need to reboot after installed android studio. Then you can allow it in System Preferences

Comment: I'm trying to allow that but "Allow" button doesn't do anything which you can see it in [this screencast](https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/2x3z0p1U3r2o390x0d1t/Screen%20Recording%202017-11-25%20at%2008.22%20PM.gif?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=1399595&v=e4263c32). What can I do at the moment?

I'm using MacOS High Sierra 10.13.1.

Answer (score 3):

To use VM acceleration on a Mac, you must install the Intel HAXM kernel extension to allow the emulator to make use of CPU virtualization extensions. Android Studio requires Mac OS X 10.8.5 or higher, up to 10.11.4 (El Capitan) Mac OS X; the kernel extension is compatible with Mac OS X 10.6.0 and higher.

To install the Intel HAXM kernel extension, follow these steps:

1. Open the SDK Manager.
2. Click the SDK Update Sites tab and then select Intel HAXM.
3. Click OK.

After the download finishes, execute the installer.
For example, it might be at this location:

```
sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM_version.dmg.
```

To begin installation, in the Finder, double-click the IntelHAXM.dmg file and then the IntelHAXM.mpkg file.

Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the installation.

After installation finishes, confirm that the new kernel extension is operating correctly by opening a terminal window and running the following command:

```
kextstat | grep intel
```

You should see a status message containing the following extension name, indicating that the kernel extension is loaded:

```
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#vm-mac)

Comment: Still does not work, same issue. When I try to uninstall HAXM from the SDK manager, the uninstall window is left blank and unresponsive. When I close this I get an additional issue where I can no longer install HAXM.

Answer (score 2):

It seemed to be an Intel HAXM issue. I resolved it by completely removing Intel HAXM.

Then I followed this [guide](https://blog.celogeek.com/201708/672/android-studio-emulator-haxm-on-mac-os-high-serria-10-13/), which basically makes you edit the install script of HAXM so the silent installation will work on Mac OS High Sierra.

Comment: broken link... this is why you should put the answer from the links into stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers provided by @AresDev & @ShubhamJain to be super helpful for the uninstallation & re-installation of HAXM, but in my case it still didn't resolve the `/dev/kvm not found` errors I was seeing. My Mac OS High Sierra was blocking the AVD / Intel extensions from running correctly, and I had to Allow it under System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Allow.

**However**, the Allow button doesn't respond in some situations! I had to quit Google Chrome, before could click Allow, as described in these posts: ["Github Karabiner Elements Issues"](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/1017)

[image: Mac Security & Privacy]